# CUDA Circle Hough Transform

Tags: image-processing, cuda, hough-transform

I am looking to improve the performance of my Circle Hough Transform algorithm and therefore I have resorted to using CUDA.  I'm currently using atomic operations in global memory to carry out the voting which I know can be slow.  However, I am unsure how to store the votes and the coordinate locations of those votes in shared memory so that I can copy the results back to global memory.

Has anyone got any suggestions/advice on how best to do this in order to achieve maximum performance for the CHT?

Many thanks in advance everyone for your time.

Comment: There is a paper ["Fast Hough Transform on GPUs: Exploration of Algorithm Trade-os"](http://parse.ele.tue.nl/system/attachments/21/original/Fast%20Hough%20Transform%20on%20GPUs%20-%20Exploration%20of%20Algorithm%20Trade-offs.pdf) which deals with the line (not circle) case, but discusses the problem you are rising on voting and suggesting a possible solution. Have you taken a look?

Comment: Yes I have seen this thank you but the voting in shared memory is different for the circle hough transform.

Comment: In terms of the question duplication, this question has been re-phrased since the answer to my previous question has not been fully addressed and is not relevant.

Comment: @JackOLantern - For GPU-bound Hough line detection, I believe the approach presented in ["Real-Time Detection of Lines using Parallel Coordinates and OpenGL"](http://medusa.fit.vutbr.cz/public/data/papers/2011-SCCG-Dubska-Real-Time-Line-Detection-Using-PC-and-OpenGL.pdf) and ["PClines – Line Detection Using Parallel Coordinates"](http://medusa.fit.vutbr.cz/public/data/papers/2011-CVPR-Dubska-PClines.pdf) is significantly faster. They do mention it being potentially generalized to circles. I've implemented this before, with voting due to additive blend modes, and it works very well.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes Brad, thanks for pointing out that. I would say that the two papers you mentioned are not using CUDA (one of them is using OpenGL), while the user is explicitly asking for a CUDA approach. Could you recommend any other algorithm using CUDA or suggest how to port the two above papers to CUDA?